# Can someone recommend a php mysql rating system that I can add to my site

Tags: php, mysql, rating-system

I'm looking for a php/mysql-based rating and comment system that has a one time license fee per site. Can someone recommend something?

I could build my own -- I already started but then I was thinking there must be something out there already.

It would be nice if it included the ability to poll people too.

Thanks

Comment: You need to be much more descriptive and specific as to what you need before we can help you.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize I was supposed to click that textbox.

Comment: I'm looking for something to do Netflix style 5 star ratings, thumbs up/down comment system like reddit, and polling. It might be three different turnkey solutions.  I'd like them to be mysql/php solutions. What other info should I provide? I've looked on hotscripts.com but would appreciate some recommendations that people may have used before.

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing a lot of sites using [Disqus](http://disqus.com/). You might give that a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you need exactly, but [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) is offering comments for your site as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could build your own threaded comment system with this class here:

http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/01/27/php-class-for-threaded-comments/

You would just have to design your table structure, its not really that hard, as for polling would be something else, i dont think you'll find an integrated soultion since, they are two different beasts.